# Extract the matching word from the list in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of names in one excel sheet A & the another excel sheet B contains the description. I want to extract the names which is in the sheet A from the description in sheet B to another cell/column

Example

**Sheet A**

```
ROW 1: PUMP
ROW 2: MOTOR
ROW 3: VALVE
ROW 4: BELT
```

**Sheet B**

```
ROW 1: FOR DIESEL ENGINE, PUMP, INJECTION, FOR DIESEL ENGINE
ROW 2: LUGGED, VALVE;BUTTERFLY;3";NB
ROW 3: BELT, DRIVE, 3V-9507
```

I need to extract the names *pump*, *valve* and *belt* into a separate column or cell from Sheet B using any formula or macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use formula, then using the `Find` formula with some error testing will work.  THe following example tests for the presence of each of your three keywords, and returns a blank if the value is not found, or an "X" if the key is found in the searched cell.

I put this formula and modify it for each of the three keys:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("PUMP",$A1,1)),"","X")
```

I copy the formula down the column and create another column for each of the tests. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

You could replace the last argument, `"X"`, with any value that you want to indicate that the keyword is *found*.